# Add Shard not reducing secondary disk size in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

My company is using mongoDB as a database.
Currently we are writing script for adding shard, once the disk value increase more than 70%.

It is working fine and adding one extra shard after threshold of 70% reaches.
The problem is that when we add shard the file size for old shards are not getting reduce as mentioned in mongo document as well.
So we connect to mongos and execute db.repairDatabase, which is working fine and reduce the file size of old shards.

The biggest problem we are facing is that the repair Database command only shrinks the storage for the primary shard, not secondary shards.

We need to shrink the secondary shard as well for automation.

Is there any command to shrink mongoDB secondary node as well?
We don't want to do resynch it: is a too long and tedious job...

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related topics only. For questions related to database administration and configuration, please ask on [dba.stackechange.com](http://dba.stackechange.com) instead of here, which is the most appropriate place to post this type of question.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed irrelevant thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The file size, once allocated, does not go down -- that space will be re-used by Mongo if your shard continues to grow.  So if you truly want to get disk space back, repairDatabase is the way to go.  You can take your secondary out of the replica set, run the repairDatabase, and bring it back into the replica set.